# How to add a swift file to Objective c pod?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am working on my own private pod and wants to add a swift file to my existing Objective-C private pod.
When I tried to add .swift file Xcode created the Pods-Tests-Bridging-Header.h file.

In-fact I mentioned this file in build settings "Objective-C Bridging Header" also.

As I have read on apple developer docs  Its says I have to import a "modfule_name-swift.h" in my files to access swift classes files.

And as separate Xcode project of Objective-C I am able to do that thing by importing "Project_name-swift.h" file in Objective-C Code.

While I am trying to same thing in Pods like "#import "Pods-Tests-swift.h" compiler couldn't recognize it and starts giving errors.

How to do that?

Comment: I think this is still work in progress https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/2222

Answer (score 0):

CocoaPods does not yet support Swift